# How to show shipping methods on product page?

Tags: magento2, shipping

Does anyone know how to display shipping methods on the product page? or Do you know any free module that does this? I need the shipping modules to appear on the product page.

Comment: Shipping method list depends on shipment address and product size and weight. I can post you an answer if you confirm that your store has only one country or use all shipping methods for all available countries for the same price.

Comment: just one country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete code. I did this using a custom module. This will show all the active shipping methods in the pdp, just below the product detail container (below the add to cart button). You can change the place where you need to show it by editing the catalog_product_view.xml

app/code/Test/Shipping/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Shipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Test/Shipping/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Shipping" >
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Test/Shipping/Block/ShippingMethods.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Shipping\Block;

class ShippingMethods implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    private $shippingMethods;

    /**
     * ShippingMethods constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods $shippingMethods
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods $shippingMethods
    )
    {
        $this->shippingMethods = $shippingMethods;
    }

    public function getShippingMethods()
    {
        return $this->shippingMethods->toOptionArray(true);
    }
}
```

app/code/Test/Shipping/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
     <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pdp.shipping_methods"
                template="Test_Shipping::shipping_methods.phtml">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Test\Shipping\Block\ShippingMethods</argument>
             </arguments>
         </block>
     </referenceContainer>
 </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Test/Shipping/view/templates/shipping_methods.phtml

```
<?php
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
foreach ($viewModel->getShippingMethods() as $sm) :
?>
<p><?= $sm['label'] ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I need the user to put the zip code in the input and show the available freight along with the value.

Comment: Then you need to implement a form to collect the zip code and submit the form using ajax, then get the response and show. You may refer the code in this class to get the available shipping methods
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods

Comment: thanks,it works very well Ajith. (: